# Force IE toolbar to always be active in C# BHO

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, toolbar, bho

I'm working on a small C# BHO and I'd like to be able to make sure the browser toolbars don't get disabled with a `window.open(url,windowname,"toolbar=no")`, and I'm wondering if theres a simple way to force that the toolbars stay enabled?

Failing that, another way to trigger the BHO would be needed, I think you can access context menus, can't you?

Comment: You realize that you can only do the things that Microsoft has exposed. They do it for consistency sake. Imagine if you had a popup window for help that was statically sized to 300x150 pixels that had 400 pixels of toolbar presented? Yes, you could whine and complain about the website designer statically sizing their windows, but that's permitted the way things are done now.

Comment: Side note: Please don't write BHOs in managed languages. You cause the .NET runtime to be loaded in the IE process and if two add-ons do this with different versions of the runtime, they will clash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the sort of thing that, in general, you can't override.  You can try using [ShowBrowserBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768268%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but if it doesn't work you will have to reconsider your design.